# iPhone stuck in Recovery Mode

Tags: itunes, icon

My phone has is displaying a symbol saying connect to iTunes, I have tried connecting to iTunes to fix this and it didn't work.

I've also tried to restore the iPhone but that also didn't work.

I have now disconnected my iPhone from the computer but the iTunes screen remains, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is telling you to connect the phone to iTunes not that it is connected.  Why was the iPhone disabled?  Apple has a support article [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203122) with some suggestions on how to address this:

> On an iPhone 6s and earlier, iPad, or iPod touch: Press and hold both
>   the Home and Top (or Side) buttons for at least 10 seconds, until you
>   see the Apple logo.
>
> If you still see the Connect to iTunes screen after you restart, you
>   need to reinstall iOS:
>
> Make sure that you're using the latest version of iTunes. Connect your
>   device to your computer using the cable that came with your device.
>   You should see this message: "There's a problem with the iPhone [your
>   device name] that requires it to be updated or restored." Click Update
>   (not Restore) to reinstall iOS and keep your personal data.

This will wipe you're iPhone completely so if there is any data on the phone that you need you should consider that first.

If the iPhone being disabled is iCloud related you will still need to enter the associated account credentials after restoring.

Comment: Reading his original text I've rewritten the question, he does suggest that he has already tried to restore the phone.

Answer (score 0):

From what you originally wrote it sounds like the phone is stuck with a screen like this:

[image]

As Jon points out in his answer, this isn't saying that your phone is connected to iTunes, it is saying that a serious and unrecoverable fault has developed with the phone's operating system and you need to use iTunes to attempt to fix it.

This message can be displayed for both software and hardware faults which affect the running of iOS.

Unfortunately with a phone in this state there is little to no chance of recovering your data if you didn't use iCloud to do backups, we need to reinstall/restore the iPhone's operating system.

There are different levels of restore, and I suggest given the situation with the device we jump straight to a DFU restore, DFU (Device Firmware Update) will restore the operating system and the boot loader.

> **Important:** Do not proceed with a DFU restore if your iPhone has been jailbroken.

The first step to getting the phone to restore in DFU mode is to put it into that mode:

1. Connect the phone to iTunes.
2. Hold the home button and sleep/wake button together until the screen goes black.
3. Release the sleep/wake button and keep holding the home button for 10 seconds.
4. The phone should remain with a black screen, but iTunes should recognise the phone is connected.
5. Follow the iTunes prompts to restore your phone.
6. The device should restart.

If the phone fails to restore after performing a DFU restore then it is likely a hardware issue with the device and you'll need to seek support from an Apple Store, or Apple Authorised Service Provider, you can find out more here: https://checkcoverage.apple.com